# i added navigation plugin and facing this class error.How to solve it?

Tags: android, kotlin, class, plugins, navigation

I added the navigation plugin in build.gradle and the following dependencies and repository in top-level build.gradle .Now they are asking me to resolve val class. I am a beginner and not being able to understand its concept.

[image]

Comment: @cactustictacs this question

Comment: Did you copy/paste code from the 'Kotlin' (i.e., for `build.gradle.kts` files) tab into your Groovy (i.e., `build.gradle`) file? Your code doesn't match the [code for adding Safe Args to your Groovy file](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args).

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes i copied it from kotlin tab..what is not matching? should I paste code from Groovy file?

Comment: A `build.gradle` file is written in Groovy, yes.

Comment: *Groovy* and *Kotlin* are two different ways of writing your Gradle *build* files - the file you're editing is written in Groovy, but you're using Kotlin syntax here with the `val`. If you click Ian's link, there's a tab above the code that switches between the Groovy and Kotlin versions - you need to use that instead. But if that tutorial you're following uses a *Kotlin* build file, you'll probably have other similar errors if you paste it into your *Groovy* one

Answer (score 1):

Nav version variable should be in project gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.1'
        ext.nav_version = "2.5.1"
    }
```